# Should the poetry of the Quriesh regarding the happening of the Elephant be trusted?

Tags: history, kaabah

As is known, [Quriesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quraysh_tribe) witnessed the happening of the Elephant when Abraha and his Army intended to destroy the Ka'bah.  But Allah sent Birds, and made the army like field of broken grass<sup>[[1]](http://quran.com/105)</sup>. The Quriesh have made poetry on this happening, and some use these poems to know what happened.  Is this right? what if it is used along side with the Authentic Ahadith of the Prophet on this Happening? what have scholars said on using these poetry, which is probably weaker than the weak Ahadith?

Comment: could you highlight what the poetry says. Is it different that the Quranic version? I'd be interested.

Comment: @TheTruthSeaker Sorry I do not know the exact lines of poetry, I just know that they made poetry about the happening of the Elephant.  As for Quranic verses, you can look at Surat Al Feel.

Answer (score 1):

**That would need to be inspected whatever poetry that is.**
In general if anything in it contradicts with what quran and sunnah/ahadees tells us, than that thing will be rejected. Otherwise it can be trusted to some extant, this incident was not long before the Prophet Muhammad PBUH was born. Thats why quran says "haven't you seen what your lord did with the people with elephants."